# JBOSS custom login module

Tags: authentication, deployment, module, jboss

I have a JBOSS EAP 6.4 with data virtualization in it. The question is, it is possible to deploy a custom login module without restarting the server ?. Also I do not want to do reload also. Also I am deploying the module using CLI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put a custom login module directly to the application you're deploying (i.e. war/jar/ear).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Since I am developing virtual database (VDB) in it I cannot include my custom module in it.